# How do I get the 'Medical Expert 2' Tonic?

Tags: bioshock

So, just after defeating *Sander Cohen*, I noticed that I was able to use his key to open *Sander Cohen's Muse Box*, which contained various goodies.  However, next to the case which contained this box, is *another* case, containing the *Medical Expert 2* tonic.  This case is not locked with a keylock, but with a numeric entry lock.  I don't have the code for this lock but something more annoying seems to be occurring: When I approach the lock, I am *not* given the usual prompts for entering codes and/or hacking.  So even if I DID have the code, I don't think I would be able to use it.

---

So, can someone please explain this to me?  Is something wrong with the PS3 version of the game?  I would also appreciate it if the information on how to find the necessary code could be given.  I am **NOT** looking for the code itself, only **how to find it**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you kill Sander Cohen the first time he showed his face in Fort Frolic?

If so, *that was a bad idea.*

First off, for completing his 'masterpiece', he would have rewarded you by unlocking the Tonic, but not if you kill him before he gets down there and unlocks it. Similarly, killing him now means you won't be able to get into his place in Olympus Heights later in the game - where you'll find, amongst other nice loot, a 'Power to the People' weapon upgrade machine.

Comment: Yikes.  I was wondering about that, I ran up and hit him with the wrench before he even said anything, and got a hypnotized big daddy to kill him.  *gah...*

Comment: I've just spoken with a friend who said that he killed Sander Cohen and took the key for the tonic case from his corpse.  Do you know anything about that?

Answer (score 3):

If you wait long enough he will look at his masterpiece and unveil the tonic. You can then collect it and kill him and get the key to his music box.

Answer (score 0):

To that's the key.  Finish his "Masterpiece" then let him open the case, take the loot and then leave.  THEN once you find him at his room in Olympus Heights and kill him, take the key to the OTHER chest off him, and then take the Bathosphere back to Fort Frolic and open the case.

Comment: To that's the key?? What does that mean?